# Is this a Stone Age artefact?

Tags: identification, archaeology, prehistory

[image]

[image]

Found these in my garden some time ago. It looks like it may have been worked but also just happens to fit into my hand. Could this be a Stone Age tool of some sort?

The second example looks more likely to be a tool.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about the location of '*my garden*'? If this is in Ireland (from your user profile), the National Museum of Ireland has [an article](https://www.museum.ie/en-IE/Collections-Research/Irish-Antiquities-Division-Collections/Collections-List-(1)/Stone-Age) which discusses the types of stone age tools found in Ireland. They are typically made of flint or chert, such as these [Bann flakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bann_flake).

Comment: I believe dating usually relies on organic material found at the same archeological layer as the stone. If its just sitting on the ground, all they can really check is how many (likely millions of) years ago the stone itself formed.

Comment: No, both have no clear traits of any lithic industry. This doesn't even look like a material that could be worked in a planned way. A tool is defined as an object that has been worked in a planned way to serve a purpose, even if the purpose may not directly be obvious.